# Can i Make Index for all columns(No write operations)?

Tags: mysql, index

Few days I just learned indexes.I my New app(running on node js) There will no write operation.And my server has 500mb of ram.Can I set Index to all of My column.I almost have 500K rows.My query is dead simple as Like this

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Limit may vary upto 10k According to users need.Right Now I am getting 0.6s In my 8Gb ram laptop.What would Happen if it is on 500Mb ram Server.Is it worth for Making Indexes in all table

Answer (score 1):

This all depends on the size of the table. You're doing a full table scan without a where clause so an index isn't going to help. The use of the rand() function for sorting is going to produce a temp table and this will harm performance. If you have a primary key you could generate a random number in the app and perform a query where a single row is selected and can make use of the clustered index. You're likely to be serving this all from memory if you're using the InnoDB storage engine.

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple ways to *efficiently* do that `SELECT` on that kind of a table.  Yes, it involves changes to the table.  And a change to the `SELECT`.

One involves adding an `AUTO_INCREMENT` `PRIMARY KEY` and *computing* random value(s) for that id.  (This is probably the best.)  For example, if there are 512345 rows:

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = CEIL(512345 * RAND());
```

Another involves adding a `DOUBLE` and indexing with it.

See my [*efficiently fetching random rows*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/doc.php/random) blog.